# C# Returns error 'Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string`' even though no int is given

Tags: c#, string, int

I am running this code:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
   Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
   string lol = Console.Read ();
   Console.WriteLine (lol);
  }
}
```

and getting this error:

```
main.cs(6,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
compiler exit status 1
```

Although I am not explicitly declaring an `int value` in the given code, which is the cause in the other articles I have read.

Comment: You're using [Console.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8), which does return an `int`. You probably want [Console.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Console.Read()` returns an `int` value for the next single character. You probably wanted `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: oml im actually slow thank you so much